# Is "contre-jour" a posh term for backlit?

Tags: lighting

Is *contre-jour* simply a posh term for backlit?  Or is there some difference?

Comment: I've never encountered the term _contre-jour_. Could you link to any reference? Indeed, now that I search for it, there are two pretty useful explanatory articles on Wikipedia which should basically have answered your question: [Contre-jour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contre-jour) and [Backlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlighting_(lighting_design))

Comment: I'm aware of the Wikipedia articles.  My thoughts are that "contre-jour" is used to describe a situation where a subject is lit from behind, whereas "backlit" suggests deliberately lighting a subject from behind.  I asked the question as I wondered if anyone in the photographic community had any further thoughts about the differences.

Comment: Sometimes, English natives get things backwards, thinking something is 'posh' when it actually means 'ordinary'. The one that always amuses me is the restaurant term 'à la carte' which was always considered 'posh' by Brits & yet isn't. It just means 'from the standard menu, available every single day'. They fail to recognise that 'table d'hôte' - the 'fixed menu' - is actually the 'posh' one, 'high table' - food made only that day & will not be available tomorrow. That being said, the examples on wikipedia point towards stylistic differences [I'd never heard of it either until today]

Comment: @Tetsujin, it's just the way language works. If there is a common native word for something, using a foreign equivalent for it must have a reason in people's minds, either semantic or stylistic. If the meaning is the same, it's even more likely such usage would be perceived as "posh".

Comment: I'm reminded of Dumb & Dumber. "What's the _soup du jour_" "It's the soup of the day" "mmm... that sounds good, I'll have that" =)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is no posh term. It is just the original term of this light situation (do not forget photography come from France). It come from French and mean "against the day" (against the light).

"Backlight" is popular because of the wide spread of English in the World.

Both words can be used interchangeably in language. And this is the situation with good amount of words (even if you limit the are only to photography). For example in most of Europe you will use stativ, in England, USA you will use tripod. You will use blende/a instead of aperture. And so on.

Comment: While this answer is fine, I think you've taken the question a bit too literally. I think what the question is really asking is _why_ this French term might be used in English now, i.e. is there any (subtle?) difference in the situations where it's used? The fact that anything (photography) was invented in any one country is no reason for the language of that country to be universally used when talking about the subject.

Comment: @osullic, I get your idea. But in such case the OP should ask this question in (if exist) English language site in SE (this become more linguistic question). And IMHO it mean the same.

Comment: I enjoy the richness of language, and I'm not questioning using a French phrase in English.  As @osulic correctly says, I'm asking if there is a difference (subtle or otherwise) in the meaning of the two terms, or are they interchangeable?

Comment: I should add, in the UK, at least, using a French term when there's a perfectly usable Anglo-Saxon alternative can be seen as being a little pretentious, and opens oneself up to the accusation of "being posh", which is typically made with humour.  I phrased my question with that in mind, which with hindsight may not be the best thing to do on an international platform such as this!

Comment: @mooie, for me the terms are interchangeable. For me it does not matter is the light is natural or artificial, you make the photo with light which is behind the object.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a posh term. It's just descriptive of the photographic (or filmic) technique of contrasting a lit scene against matte, or lit-through-doorway technique. It literally means "against daylight" in French.

Perhaps the most famous, and perhaps most-copied, example of *contre-jour* in cinema is the closing shot of *The Searchers*, one of the finest films of the John Ford / John Wayne collaboration:

[image]

Quentin Tarantino copied it in homage, in Inlgorious Basterds:

[image]